# How can I redirect from "/collections/all" page to "/collections/all/shop-all" page from Shopify?

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid, shopify-cli

I have this problem here where I'm Liquid Engineer and I'm managing a store project called *'Briogeo'* where I got a little problem right here where Ima tryin' to redirect from this store ***"/collections/all"*** page to "**collections/all/shop-all"**.

**e.g** If the principal link store is *'https://www.briogeohair.com/'* and when I click on **"COLLECTIONS/ALL"** -> **"COLLECTIONS/ALL/SHOPS-ALL"**.

As the complete links will be like: *"https://www.briogeohair.com/collections/all"* but I want to redirect to *"https://www.briogeohair.com/collections/all/shop-all"*. Because both links are generating traffic to have visits.

But I think is impossible because Shopify doesn't allow it to edit but I was looking about a great solution applying is this possible with HTML5, JavaScript or Liquid.

So, the point is.. If there is possible to do that?

The Briogeo's owners told me this:

(This is causing internal competition between 2 pages due to the irrational distribution of authority between "/shop-all" and "/all" pages and making it hard for search engines to serve the expected URL in search results for relevant keywords, such as *"Briogeo products"*, *"Briogeo supplements"*, *"healthy aging supplements"* and similar queries.

We recommend to updating the "/all" page and sending all authority signals to it because Google already prefers it for the majority of search queries. It should exclude the duplicate "/shop-all" URL from search results and potentially improve the rankings for relevant generic search queries.)

To can redirect from "https://www.briogeohair.com/collections/all" to "https://www.briogeohair.com/collections/all/shop-all". To have more traffic of visits.

Comment: So you explicitly want to do _the opposite_ of what the owner of Briogeo recommends? It seems to me that the owner suggests to eliminate `/collections/all/shop-all` and send all traffic to `/collections/all` instead because Google already prefers it, whereas you want to know how to send all traffic from `/collections/all` to `/collections/all/shop-all`. It's a bit hard to understand what you want to achieve, so I might be wrong.

Comment: @David Sorry! I got misunderstanding what I said, I missed that he agreed to keep both pages, so the thing is I want is to know is How to Set Up as a 301 Redirect from collections/all to /collections/all/shop-all in Shopify. Is that possible to do that?